# Sms message sending not working in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, smsmanager

I'm trying to create a program that schedules SMS message events that sends them to your own phone.  For some reason it doesn't work.  I made an SmsAlarm class that extends BroadcastReceiver and its role is to set/cancel the alarm.  Here is the class:

```
public class SmsAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private int hour1, minute1, hour2, minute2, frequency;
private PendingIntent pi;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String phoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int currentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if (currentHour >= hour1 && currentHour <= hour2 && currentMinute >= minute1 && currentMinute <= minute2) {
        String[] messages = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.messages);
        manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, phoneNumber, messages[(int)(Math.random() * messages.length)], pi, null);
    }
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SmsAlarm.class);
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * frequency, pi); //millisecond * second * minutes
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SmsAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
//getters and setters after this method
```

In order to use the same scheduler every time the app is opened, we serialize the SmsManager object the first time the app is run after installation.  These are the saveAlarm and loadAlarm methods inside my MainActivity class:

```
public void saveAlarm(Context context){
    try{
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(manager);
    os.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public SmsAlarm loadAlarm(Context context){

    try{
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
    ObjectInputStream is=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    try {
        manager=(SmsAlarm) is.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    is.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return manager;
}
```

In MainActivity.java I have a private instance variable of SmsManager and inside the onCreate method, if the app was never opened before, I set manager equal to a new SmsManager:

```
if (!welcomeScreenShown) {
        manager = new SmsAlarm();
        saveAlarm(getApplicationContext());
        String whatsNewTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.whatsNewTitle);
        String whatsNewText = getResources().getString(R.string.whatsNewText);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle(whatsNewTitle).setMessage(whatsNewText).setPositiveButton(
                R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
        editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
    }
```

The configuration page has two Time Pickers that let the user choose their time constraints and a frequency spinner with multiple options for the frequency of receiving messages.  For testing, I used every minute.  This code runs inside onCreate of MainActivity of the config screen hasn't been shown yet:

```
if (configScreenShown)
    {
        manager = loadAlarm(getApplicationContext());
        //get the values from the SharedPreferences
        hour1 = setPrefs.getInt("hour1", 0);
        hour2 = setPrefs.getInt("hour2", 0);
        minute1 = setPrefs.getInt("minute1", 0);
        minute2 = setPrefs.getInt("minute2", 0);
        int freqInt = setPrefs.getInt("frequency", 0);
        frequencySet=freqInttoString(freqInt);

    }
```

It calls loadAlarm to retrieve a previously used SmsAlarm from the last time the app was opened.  I think there's a problem with SmsAlarm.java and I'm thinking about getting rid of that class and putting all the logic in MainActivity.

The manifest file:

```
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        <data android:scheme="sms" /> 
        <data android:port="8901" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a permission to be added to `AndroidManifest.xml` file if you have to send a message from your phone.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Have you added this? I think that you might be missing this!

Check [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android).

Comment: I already already included that, I'll post the manifest file.